# In Memoriam: Vernor Vinge

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Vernor Vinge, father of the tech singularity, has died at age 79](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2024/03/vernor-vinge-father-of-the-tech-singularity-has-died-at-age-79/)

> On Wednesday, author David Brin announced that Vernor Vinge, sci-fi author, former professor, and father of the technological singularity concept, died from Parkinson's disease at age 79 on March 20, 2024, in La Jolla, California. The announcement came in a Facebook tribute where Brin wrote about Vinge's deep love for science and writing.
>
> "A titan in the literary genre that explores a limitless range of potential destinies, Vernor enthralled millions with tales of plausible tomorrows, made all the more vivid by his polymath masteries of language, drama, characters, and the implications of science," wrote Brin in his post.
>
> As a sci-fi author, Vinge won Hugo Awards for his novels A Fire Upon the Deep (1993), A Deepness in the Sky (2000), and Rainbows End (2007). He also won Hugos for novellas Fast Times at Fairmont High (2002) and The Cookie Monster (2004). As Mike Glyer's File 770 blog notes, Vinge's novella True Names (1981) is frequency cited as the first presentation of an in-depth look at the concept of "cyberspace."
>
> Vinge first coined the term "singularity" as related to technology in 1983, borrowed from the concept of a singularity in spacetime in physics. When discussing the creation of intelligences far greater than our own in an 1983 op-ed in OMNI magazine, Vinge wrote, "When this happens, human history will have reached a kind of singularity, an intellectual transition as impenetrable as the knotted space-time at the center of a black hole, and the world will pass far beyond our understanding."
>
> In 1993, he expanded on the idea in an essay titled "The Coming Technological Singularity: How to Survive in the Post-Human Era."

Comment: _Rainbows End_ though awarded, is disliked by many, but I really liked it.  [Here's an obituary of Vinge](https://instapundit.substack.com/p/rip-vernor-vinge) that goes into it and its relevance today.  I also liked _Fast Times At Fairmont High_, a story written earlier (I believe) that is in a quite similar world, same characters, but different ...  _True Names_, of course, is epically good.